# Android App crash while reading command output java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, android

I want to run root commands via my Android application which consists of background Service by using function below:

```
    public static String runAsRoot(String cmd) {
        String output = "";
        try {
            Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"su", "-c", "system/bin/sh"});
            DataOutputStream stdin = new DataOutputStream(p.getOutputStream());
            stdin.writeBytes(cmd + "\nexit\n");
            InputStream stdout = p.getInputStream();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[128];
            int read;
            int loopCount = 0;

//read method will wait forever if there is nothing in the stream
//so we need to read it in another way than while((read=stdout.read(buffer))>0)
            while (true) {
                try {
                    loopCount++;
                    read = stdout.read(buffer);
                    output += new String(buffer, 0, read);
                    if (read < 128 || loopCount > 5) {
                        //we have read everything
                        break;
                    }
                }catch (Exception e){

                }
            }

            //Close streams
            stdin.close();
            stdout.close();
            p.destroy();

            Log.e("Command output:", output);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            output = "exceptionFound";
        }

        return output;
    }
```

and I am calling this function multiple times by creating Threads:

```
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {

                            try {

//                                if (notOnTop>10){
//                                    runAsRoot("reboot now");
//                                }

                                int isRunning = controlTopApp();
                                if (isRunning == 0) {
                                    Log.d("Control_OnTop", "Attendance notOnTop,bringToFront");
                                    runAsRoot("am start -n berk.can.myapp.anotherapp/.MainActivity");
                                } else if (isRunning == 1) {
                                    Log.d("Control_OnTop", "Attendance");
                                }

                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                Log.e("Runnable App E.", Log.getStackTraceString(e));
                            }

                        }
                    }).start();
```

I want to get output of root commands so I am giving a specified value for read (here it is 128). but after a while it gives this error and my service is killed:

```
02-28 16:34:41.751 22377-22759/? W/System.err: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=128; regionStart=0; regionLength=-1
02-28 16:34:41.760 22377-22759/? W/System.err:     at java.lang.String.failedBoundsCheck(String.java:508)
02-28 16:34:41.760 22377-22759/? W/System.err:     at java.lang.String.<init>(String.java:225)
02-28 16:34:41.760 22377-22759/? W/System.err:     at java.lang.String.<init>(String.java:149)
02-28 16:34:41.760 22377-22759/? W/System.err:     at berk.can.myapp.controllerservice.MyService.runAsRoot(MyService.java:271)
02-28 16:34:41.760 22377-22759/? W/System.err:     at berk.can.myapp.controllerservice.MyService.controlTopApp(MyService.java:176)
02-28 16:34:41.760 22377-22759/? W/System.err:     at berk.can.myapp.controllerservice.MyService.access$000(MyService.java:27)
02-28 16:34:41.760 22377-22759/? W/System.err:     at berk.can.myapp.controllerservice.MyService$TimeTask$1.run(MyService.java:103)
02-28 16:34:41.760 22377-22759/? W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Can it be because of more than one threads run at the same time and why I can't handle Exception by try-catch and continue running my Service ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you reach end of file `EOF` `InputStream.read(...)` will return `-1`, you'll have to check for that before constructing the string, before `output += new String(buffer, 0, read);`

Doing something like this:

```
while (true) {
    try {
        loopCount++;
        read = stdout.read(buffer);
        if(read == -1){
            break;
        }
        output += new String(buffer, 0, read);
        if (read < 128 || loopCount > 5) {
            //we have read everything
            break;
        }
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Should prevent the exception.

Comment: then my while loop should be like that, right? :

while (true) {
                try {
                    loopCount++;
                    read = stdout.read(buffer);
                    if (read==-1){
                        break;
                    }
                    output += new String(buffer, 0, read);
                    if (read < 128 || loopCount > 5) {
                        //we have read everything
                        break;
                    }
                }catch (Exception e){

                }
            }

Comment: @BerkCaN Yes, that should prevent the exception.

Comment: Thank you so much, you are a lifesaver, and may I ask why try-catch can't handle Exception and causes my service to stop ?

Comment: @BerkCaN I'm not sure, I can't see your imports but if you're catching `java.lang.Exception` exceptions, the program should keep running even when this happens.

Comment: now you said that, I checked my code; even though I am using try catch blocks, there was no 'java.lang.Exception' import in the code, but I think as we don't need to import anything if it is inside java.lang package, isn't it right ?

Comment: @BerkCaN Yes, I think that is the case for Android applications as well but the default class `java.lang.Exception` will be overridden if you have another import for a class with that name or a class with that name in the same package.

Comment: Hm, I will search more about Exception handling in Android then it might be another case in my situation, thanks for the knowledge, this is the accepted answer for the question

Comment: @BerkCaN I'm glad I could help. Good luck